# How to use Afreechart library to make Gantt graphics

Tags: android, graph, charts, gantt-chart

I want to use the library Afree chartto do an app with a Gantt graph (also called timeline graph). I thought i can use this library after watching this picture [enter link description here](http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/images/XYBarChartDemo07.png)

And so i have to create a Bar Chart, anyone is using this program can help me?

Comment: hi did u get the way to implement the gantt chart